# Photoshop Multiple Seamless Tiles One Image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, seamless

I need to create some tiles for my top-down tile based game. I can create seamless images in photoshop using the offset filter, but I want to create 4 seamless images from one texture, so that my game does not seem boring and repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could first divide the texture in question into 4 equal sized images, and then apply the offset filter to each one, making each seamless.  Of course, it won't look exactly the same as it did when it was a single whole texture, but it would look close.

Comment: Each tile would be seamless with itself, but not with the other three tiles though.

Comment: I agree... So... here is another possibility.  Take the original texture you wish to make seamless, and apply the offset filter.  It is now seamless.  Now, determine where the offset filter did not adjust the initial image (usually you can set this limitation at the filter before you apply it).  Alter the image in the center, making it different from the original, and save it as a new image.  Repeat indefinitely for tiles that would be similar to the original, but still unique (since you altered each in the middle).

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I'll give that a go, thanks!